# CPP intresting thing with conditionsl statement

Tags: c++

```
if(cout<<"h"){}
```

this gives me an output

```
h
```

Any idea why, I have tried many variations of it and it still works.

Comment: `cout` is literally _made_ to produce output. Why should it _not_ give an output?

Comment: In other words, why did you expect something else to happen? *What* did you expect that code would accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the if statement needs to evaluate the `condition` you give into it, plus, `stream`s are implicitly convertible to `bool`.